# VUFORIA Build Support for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Cannot import Vuforia SDK for Unity.

**Unity Version 2019.2.6f1**

**Unity Hub Version 2.1.2.0**

**Vuforia SDK for Android Version 8.3**

I'm not able to use Vuforia SDK in Unity.When i did the installation there was no downloadable file for Vuforia Android Build Support.

I went to build settings and added Vuforia Augmented Reality Support for Android, Unity just stops responding. Is there any solution or should i just prefer a older version of Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Unity Version you don't manually import the Vuforia SDK anymore.

It is now the [Vuforia Engine AR](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.ptc.vuforia.engine@latest/index.html) Package and was moved to the [PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html).

All you have to do is

1. open <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Package Manager</kbd>

   [image]
2. Switch the filter from `InProject` to `All Pakcages`

   [image]
3. Scroll down or search for `Vuforia Engine AR`

   [image]
4. Hit <kbd>Install</kbd>

   [image]

Unity now automatically downloads and imports this package which you later can find listed under the `Packages` section in the ProjectView

[image]

---

Or as you probably ment simply tick the `Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported*` option in the PlayerSettings (which basically does the same)

[image]

---

This should be working with `2019.2.6f1` since I'm currently using it.